# When sharing a link, can't specify custom picture, title, description fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a new app using version 2.9 of the Facebook PHP API. When trying to share a link, I can't force the post to contain the picture, title, and description fields I've specified.

Instead, Facebook uses Open Graph to dynamically pull an image URL from the shared page as well as its title and description. However, these are not what I want to appear on Facebook.

Here is some sample code:

```
$linkData = [
        'message' => 'A new test post to Facebook',
        'link' => 'https://www.example.com',
        'picture' => 'https://www.example.com/image.jpg',
        'name' => 'Test name',
        'caption' => 'Test caption',
        'description' => 'Test description'
];


try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Is there any way to force Facebook to use the custom parameters I've specified?

Comment: No. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is a "90-day deprecation", and any idea why this is buried so deeply in the changelog? I admit I did review the changelog but did not see this or understand what it meant.

Comment: It means it was removed with introduction of API v2.9, and for all other versions 90 days after v2.9 was introduced. And the documentation for /user/feed, page/feed and the Share and Feed dialog has been updated to reflect/mention this, so I would hardly call it deeply buried.

Comment: Do you know of any workaround? I see a feature disappearing, but nothing new to take its place. This makes the API less powerful and, in my case, nearly useless. I don't have the option of applying Open Graph tags on every page that might be shared.

Comment: There won't be any, other than specifying this via Open Graph meta tags right at the source. I am pretty sure this is part of fighting the whole fake news stuff - and if this makes the API "less powerful" in some people's eyes, so be it. It simply has become a necessity to restrict this.